# Image spacing between columns in a gridview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a gridview in which I have images. The problem I have is that there is spacing between the columns. I don't want any spacings. If you check the picture below I don't have spacing between the rows.

[image]

Here is my gridview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">
</GridView>
```

Here is the code:

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

What I want to do is to have same amount of spacing between all the images.

Comment: There are available `android:horizontalSpacing=""`
 `android:verticalSpacing=""` attribute for `GridView`.

Comment: I used android:horizontalSpacing="0" android:verticalSpacing="0" attribute but there is still spacing between columns.

Comment: I have tried everything. I always get some spacing between the columns like the image above. I have also searched a lot and it seems nobody have solved the problem with spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your `GridView`.

```
 android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

Change this

```
 android:stretchMode="none"
```

UPDATE:

set this property for your `ImageView`.

```
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
```

Use:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>

 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
 imageview.setpadding(8,8,8,8);
```

Comment: I removed it and did nothing.

Comment: Okay means you don't want any horizontal or vertical space. isn't it?

Comment: I want same amount of spacing between all the images. Now the horizontal spacing is more than the vertical.

Comment: The images is not drawn on the screen when I use this: android:stretchMode="none"

Comment: Now I can see the drawing. But half of the drawing is out of the screen.

Comment: Is it going vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Also change your GridView height and width to match_parent instead of wrap_content.

Comment: The images are pressed horizontally to each other.

Comment: `imageview.setpadding(8,8,8,8);` use this line for your `Imageview`.

Comment: I used             imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(4,4,4,4); But why is the w: 85 and h:85

Comment: Just check my answer again. you will find ur solution.

Comment: why is the w: 85 and h:85 because its create a 85x85 size image.

Comment: When I use this: imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0); there should not be any padding. It is no spacing between rows but still a gap between the column.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
 android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two attributes....

```
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dip"
```

**Update:**
Set `android:stretchMode` attribute value to `none` instead of `columnWidth`...this will fix the space problem between columns.

```
android:stretchMode="none"
```

Comment: Now there is a space between the rows. But the space between column is still the same.

Comment: When I used android:stretchMode="none" the squares where not drawn on the screen.